# Notification bar icon not removed onDestroy

Tags: android, notifications

Inside my application I use a Service that shows up an icon in the notification bar, when its running. The notification is created as follows:

```
private void showNotification() {

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_action_video, "Nachricht 1", System.currentTimeMillis());

    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, VIRAPRecorderActivity.class), 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getString(R.string.app_name), getString(R.string.recorder_running),
            intent);

    // user cannot dismiss notification
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    nm.notify(12345, notification);

}
```

In the onDestroy() method of my service I try to cancel the notification like this:

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nm.cancel(12345);
```

This does not work. The notification is still visible, although the app is closed. Why? How to solve?

Comment: try `nm.cancelAll();` and also remove `FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT`

Comment: NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.cancel(12345); try to used this

Comment: @RajanBhavsar this did not help.

Comment: use setAutoCancel(true) method

Comment: @m0rpheu5: This does not help, because then the user is able to remove the notification, what I dont want him to able to.

Answer (score 0):

If you close the app the service will not stop. You have to stop the service explicitly then only the `onDestroy()` of the service will be called.

Comment: onDestroy gets called. But it gets called before the services onDestroy. Might that be a problem?

Comment: It is a bound service and the service is destroyed, when I unbind it from my activity. The services onDestroy() gets called.